# json file items inserted as single item in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

This is my first time using mongodb and I have a products.json file in the format of

```
 {"products":[ {} , {}  , {}  ] }
```

and when I inserted it to mongodb with the command :

```
mongoimport --db databaseName --collection collectioname  --file products.json
```

I got in my collection the products.json as  a single document with a single object id not a doc with an id for every `{}` object in my array .Obviously my json format is incorrect and I would really appreciate your help with this since I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described , what you need is to import with --collection products , and have your products in the json file to be as follow:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

Or you can modify the file content as follow:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

and add --jsonArray  to the mongoimport command to load the array objects as separate documents ...